# I don't understand dividing in congruence equations.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I need to find the smallest possible value of x when:

x = 2 mod3 &

x = 3 mod5

My first step was to put it in the form 1 + 3a = 2mod5. It then becomes 3a = 1 mod 5 (presumably because 1 mod 5 = 1?). However the next step should be a = 2 mod5 but I don't understand the step to get to 2 mod5.

Comment: "presumably because 1 mod 5 = 1?"  Not really.  $1 + 3a \equiv 2 \mod 5 \iff 1 + 3a - 1 \equiv 2 -1 \mod 5$ so $3a \equiv 1 \mod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Multiply both sides of $3a \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

i would write $$x=2+3m,x=3+5n$$ from here we get
$$2+3m=3+5n$$ and we have to solve$$3m-5n=1$$ for integers $$m,n$$ solving this Diophantine equation we obtain $$m=2+5k,n=1+3k$$ from here you will get your solutions

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve $3a \equiv 1 \mod 5$ so ...

1) Intuition.

$1 \equiv 6 \mod 5 \equiv 2*3$ so $ a = 2$.

2) Just keep adding $5$ until you get something.

$3a \equiv 1 \mod 5$.  but $3\not \mid 1$.  So add $5$.

$3a \equiv 1+5 = 6 \mod 5$.  And $3|6$ so $a = \frac 63 = 2$.

3) you can do it that hard way:

....

$3a = 1\equiv 5 \implies 3a = 1 + 5k \implies$

$3a = 3k + 1 + 2k \implies 1+2k \equiv 0 \mod 3 \implies 2k \equiv -1 \mod 3$

$\implies 2k = 3m - 1 = 2m + m- 1 \implies$

$m-1 \equiv 0 \mod 2 \implies m \equiv 1 \mod 2$

So let $m = 1$.

Then $2k = 3m - 1 =3-1 = 2 \implies $k = 1$

So $3a = 1 + 5k = 1 + 5 = 6 \implies$

$a = 2$.

The above seems pointlessly tedious, but it is basically Euclid's Algorithm and if $\gcd (3,5) = 1$ willl always work.

For harder cases it is useful but for simple cases your intuition should just tell you.

Less obvious.

$74a \equiv 1 \mod 981$.

Intuition?  I have none.

Add $981$ so $74a \equiv 1 + 981 \equiv 982 \mod 981$ ... we could be here all night....

$74a = 1 + 981k = 1 + 13*74k + 19k$ so $19k + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 74$

$19k \equiv -1 \mod 74$ so $19k = -1 + 74m = -1 + 4*19m -2m$

$-1 - 2m \equiv 0 \mod 19$ so $2m \equiv -1 \mod 19$ so $2m = -1 + 19n$

so $2m = - 1 + n + 2*9n$

So $n-1 \equiv 0 \mod 2$

So $n \equiv 1 \mod 2$.

Let $n = 1$.  $2m = -1 + 1 + 2*9*1 = 18$ so $m = 9$.

So $19k = -1 + 74m= -1 + 74*9 = 1+666$ (ooh, scary) $ = 665 = 19*35$

So $k = 35$ and $74a = 1 + 981k = 1 + 981*35 = 34336=464*74$

So $a \equiv 464\mod 981$